# Windows service with flash

Tags: flash, windows-services

I have a swf (flash) program that I projected to an exe file. I would like to run it as a windows service. I am able to install it as a service however the program does not work under local system account.

If I change the log on as settings of the service to log as the current user, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know why it would not work under the local system account?

Comment: Just curious: what does it do, as a service?

Comment: Connects to cirrus and allows peer-to-peer connection between a computer and a web browser running flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Flash needs user account with LocalSettings folders, shared objects and browser settings. It just not meant to be used as a system service.

Comment: I am now using the "Network Service" account to launch the flash file. This account is a standard windows service level account and it works.